# How to catch all requests that are non-json back to a specific action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, routes, pushstate

I have a Rails backend API that works with AngularJS. Angular is configured to use HTML5 pushState, which means that Angular URLs appear in the browser without the `#`; this change introduces the issue that users may copy the URL from the browser and enter it manually later on, which means the user will be handled directly by Rails(which is only an API backend in my context) instead of AngularJS.

For example requests such as:

```
/resources
```

should be redirected to `main#my_action` instead of `resources#index`.

On the other handle, requests such as:

```
/resources.json
```

should still be handled by `resources#index`.

So, I want all requests to the backend that doesn't end with `.json` to be redirected to `main#index`(which should delegate the url to AngularJS), so Angular can handle them.

I tried different combinations of routes but none of them seems to be redirecting requests correctly.

```
# routes.rb

constraints(format: 'json') do 

# API routes here...

end

get '*', to: 'main#index'
# or..
get '', to: 'main#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out constraining routes doesn't work as excpeted, however, using the scopes solved it.

```
scope format: true, constraints: {format: 'json') do 

# Api routes...

end

# Catch all
get '*path', to: 'main#index'
```

This will redirect anything other than the JSON API requests to the main page, which will get Angular to handle the URLs as someone might expect.

Keep in mind that routes before the catch all line will actually bypass the redirection, which could be useful at times.